# Is it allowed to make a simple automatic program that earns you the Fanatic badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, banning

Fanatic badge: Visit the site each day for 100 consecutive days. (Days are counted in UTC.)

If some person would make a very simple program that

- loads Stack Overflow every day
- puts that program on (for example) a Raspberry Pi that he dumps somewhere
- lets it run at least 100 days

would he risk to be banned from Stack Overflow?

Comment: At least it would show that some person is indeed fanatic ;)

Comment: Here, have an `over-engineering` badge - just set SO as your [home page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95314?hl=en-GB).

Comment: Well, I didn't get banned for this.

Comment: What do you think this is, [Cookie Clicker](http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/)?

Comment: If you care that much about the fanatic badge, then why not actually come here everyday?

Comment: Some accounts on this site are bots, created by users, who do _nothing but automated activity 24/7_ (hi [SmokeDetector](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3735529/smokedetector) and [Closey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4424245/closey)). I'd argue that, as long as you don't engage in harmful or fraudulent activity (upvote yourself, make automated edits, ...), automation is completely fine. After all, [Closey actually has the Fanatic badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/fanatic?userid=4424245). :P

Comment: Wow I never thought of that. Since you said that maybe I'll try just for the fun. However even *that* can't/won't stop me from coming to stackoverflow.

Comment: Well, try it. It's not as simple as a `wget`. Even `lynx` is not enough. To me it seems you have to run some JavaScript.

Comment: @Icepickle: it's easy to miss a day when you're on holidays or ill.

Comment: I remember a question on super user where a user asked for a windows task that would boot, launch browser, log in and shutdown again to get this badge. I'll try to find it.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Not if you're a _Fanatic_ it isn't. "_Yes, I've just had open-heart surgery, but I just need to check my count of Meaningless Internet Points..._". And _holidays_ are for light-weights :-)

Comment: I don't understand. You mean you want to *avoid* visiting the site for 100 consecutive days? Why would anyone....?

Comment: I simply put a shortcut to my SO profile on my phone and hit it dayly.

Comment: What would be the point? What value is a fraudulently earned badge? It has no monetary value, it can be pretty easily proven that you didn't earn it legitimately via SEDE, and (personally, anyway) cheating to get something I didn't earn isn't satisfying in any way.

Comment: Can I have a fanatic fanatic badge, where I got on SO manually like some eleventh century peasant?

Comment: I have created recurring reminders in Google Calendar and I get reminders daily once on my android so I  login immediately. Although I do agree that I had missed even single day, it resets to 0.

Answer (score 48):

Ok, so, I'd like to put my confession here.

Once I've seen the "Fanatic" badge description

> Visit the site each day for 100 consecutive days

I thought "*Hey! It can be automated*".

So I wrote a simple bot ([sources](https://github.com/Deliaz/so_visitor)) and put it into the Cron on my VPS.

**How it worked**: I used nightmare.js for login and visit my SO profile page. It also was grabbing the badge progress and sending it to me using Mailgun. 
In order to run headlessly, I ran it with Xvfb (X virtual framebuffer).

Every morning at 10.05 AM (my local time) the bot has been visited SO and send me a notification email.

Today I achieved the Fanatic badge.

Btw, I (human) visited SO as usual, but I am sure that I did not do that for 100 consecutive days.

Comment: "Hey! It can be automated". My exact first thoughts on seeing this too.

Comment: That still requires that you'll use your computer every day. Ever thought about using it with a server/cloud?

Comment: @O.Aroesti I run it in my VPS, which is a server in a cloud

Comment: Here's a solution which a̶b̶u̶s̶e̶s̶  relies on GitHub Actions and doesn't need VPS or VMs to be set up: https://github.com/connorads/stackoverflow-fanatic

Answer (score 31):

In general, I'd think of that as unethical and cheating.

However, StackOverflow is a site dedicated to programming, and programming is using computer to solve problems, so I'd consider using computer to solve problem (getting a badge) fine here.

Answer (score 29):

<strike>You</strike> Some person would almost certainly not be banned for this. I'm not sure just loading the main page is enough to get the badge, though. I think you'd have to take some action like voting, commenting, etc. to count as an "action" for the day (see the comments on [this old post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175414/1288)).

Comment: Even just clicking on anything on the homepage (e.g. going to your profile) counts as an "action" so there isn't even any real engagement (comments/votes) required.

Comment: @Keiwan I suppose that's a good thing. I'd hate to think someone might script upvoting a random post each day just to get a badge.

Comment: Two gold badges actually, there's one specifically for voting as well ;) The incentives are just too damn high...

Comment: You only need to make sure, you’re not loading a cached version of the page. My day count got reset because of this once… =/

Comment: favoriting / unfavoriting some question would likely be the least troublesome way to simulate activity

Comment: I earned the *Fanatic* a couple days ago. Visiting the main page on the mobile app does not suffice. But visiting my own profile did. I was doing a lot of review during that period. But there were a couple days where I just didn't find the time to contribute and thankfully visiting your own profile is a *real* action **currently**.

Answer (score 10):

My approach to this was to add my SO **profile** to my list of homepage tabs, so that whenever I opened Chrome, it would be loaded in the background. This way you're not actually botting, so if there was any rule against it (not that there is, to my knowledge), you would not be breaching it.

I can confirm that this method works, my fanatic badge is a testament to this.

Comment: Still, you have to use your computer for 100 consecutive days.

Comment: @el.pescado Yes, so?

Comment: This is true, though not an issue for me. Others may be in different circumstances, though.

Comment: @MrLister I lost my progress toward the badge because I went to visit someone and my phone died at some point. When I got to my charger it was already too late

Comment: @EpicKip I can totally relate. That happened to me once, in 2015, so I'm only at 835 days consecutive now.

Comment: I did the same, stackoverflow is my homepage, though I did not know there was a badge for it. Got it on multiple sites now.