# Stack Overflow Gold Badge

Tags: discussion

I want to work towards my first gold badge on Stack Overflow and was wondering which gold badge was the most achievable.

Is there a way to get badges "quicker" than usual? I would like to have some badges to display as a form of achievement.

Comment: You can see the gold badges listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=gold) - which one has been achieved most times might be a reasonable proxy to easiness, but it'll depend partly on how you engage with the site.

Comment: The **easiest** but not the quickest gold badge to earn is the [***Fanatic***](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/fanatic)

Comment: Maybe the [Fanatic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/fanatic) badge is the easiest. You also have the flagging privilege, so you can also aim to get the [Marshal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1298/marshal) badge. Hang out in [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics) chat room and appropriately flag the post that appear.

Comment: You're better off starting slow, many of the bronze badges are very easy to obtain.

Comment: i agree. Fanatic is indeed not that hard. Also one more question... Is it "okay" to write a bot, who litterally logs in for me every day? I would like to do that, but if that isnt allowed, i will not do it

Comment: @Enripro I remember I read somewhere that SO does some checking to differentiate between a human and a bot (I don't remember exactly, don't mark my word for this one).  You can read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351223/is-it-allowed-to-make-a-simple-automatic-program-that-earns-you-the-fanatic-badg) post I found on meta, for more information.

Comment: Whether or not such a bot would be detected is a different question from whether it's *allowed* or whether it's appropriate. You say: "I would like to have some badges to display as a form of achievement." But the "achievement" of the Fanatic badge is for visiting the site for 100 consecutive days. Writing a bot to do that isn't the same as doing it yourself. Do you really want to display achievements you haven't actually achieved? What's the point of that?

Comment: Well i agree with you. BUT as a matter of fact, it is not like, I didnt earn it. I would build the bot by myself, so its in some sort "deserved". I am assuming, you mean its not the "nobel and brave" way, of doing this, but its a way.

Comment: Don't be disappointed if the bot doesn't work. It's very possible the criteria for the badge may include some sort of minimal interaction like opening a question. After all, that's what a fanatic *would* do when visiting.

Comment: I'd actually say that [_**Electorate**_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/44/electorate) is the easiest gold badge to achieve; they only thing it requires is that you vote on questions. If used strategically, you get 40 post votes per day, meaning you can get this badge in just _15_ days from a new account if you really went for it.

Comment: @zcoop98 i will try! i will eventually get one... thats for shure

Comment: @Enripro: No, if you did this you wouldn't deserve a badge that claimed you'd visited every day for 100 days. You would deserve a badge that claimed you'd written a bot. They're not the same thing. I've got lots of gold badges on Stack Overflow - does that mean I should be able to claim I've got an Olympic gold medal for the 100m sprint?

Answer (score -18):

Following this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=gold,
you can see how many account have gotten a certain golden badge.

The easiest seems to be:

> Famous Question

So, question with 10,000 views

Comment: It's not too easy anymore.

Comment: You think it's easy to write a question that attracts 10,000 views? Take a look at when these questions were posted and when the author was awarded a gold badge. It can sometimes take years.

Comment: Case in point the most recent gold badge was awarded to a question posted in 2015 https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question

Comment: true. I do not hink, thats easy. Also... What is wrong with stackoverflow? Damn they really migrated this, becausse a simular question was asked in meta... OKAY

Comment: @Enripro500 No, they do not migrate your question because a similar question was asked here, but because your question is better suited when ask here. Your question isn't programming related, but rather a discussion about the site itself, [which is what the meta site does](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: Nothing (well, apart from issues unrelated to this one) is wrong with Stack Overflow. Main site is for programming questions only. İt *must not* be used for meta discussions (or discussions of any kind - it is a Q&A site). The place for meta narrative is on meta, hence the migration.

Comment: "_true. I do not hink, thats easy_" It isn't _meant_ to be easy. That's why it is a gold badge.

Comment: I guess, you guys are right... I am new, and i did not know, that meta is made, for such discussions. Im sorry. But i cant close my question... Or can i?

Comment: can i delete my question? It says, i cant...

Comment: @Enripro Don't worry about deleting the question, no harm done!

Comment: @zcoop98 thank you... I am really trying my best tho.